# How to edit a Rich Text Field in an SPFX Webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, fabric

I am creating an spfx webpart to allow users to edit some items in a list. I am trying to use office-ui-fabric-react for all the controls as recommended. The list has a rich text field(Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks). How do I enable editing of such a field in an spfx webpart?

Comment: Another RTE by Microsoft is roosterjs Check it out in the below link [Github repo for roosterjs](https://github.com/microsoft/roosterjs)

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Office UI Fabric](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components) doesn't currently have a rich text editor control. There have been requests for a rich text control, but the response right now from developers is that [*"[they] are not currently working on WYSIWYG editor, but it is a good suggestion... [they] will keep this on [their] radar..."*](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/4611#issuecomment-382814603)_

That said there are a couple examples out there of integrating rich text editors within a SPFx solution:

- **TinyMCE Editor:** Found within [SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts) samples repository in GitHub there is a [sample SPFx WebPart integrating TinyMCE Editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-tinymce).
- **CKEditor:** There is a [TechNet Article about integrating CKeditor5 within a SPFx solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51235.sharepoint-framework-aka-spfx-with-ckeditor5-pnp-js-officeuifabric-peoplepicker-and-much-more.aspx) and with that an accompanying [code sample](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-framework-aka-a2878107)

It also looks like a **future version** of the [@pnp/spfx-controls-react](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/) ***may*** have a rich text control. I noticed [pull request #211](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/pull/211) where user **hugoabernier** has shared *"...a rich text control that mimics the out-of-the-box SharePoint rich text editor (as much as possible), using Quill.js..."*

Comment: Needs tweaking, but love this approach: http://damjan.blogspot.com/2020/04/sharepoint-online-use-classic-rich-text.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using  CKEditor. Works great.

Comment: The guy who posted the 'answer' is the author.

Comment: I tried to upload the image but its not working.